# Negative Scenario on login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

During the login process, on the wrong password attempt, I need to change a few flags and attributes in the user directory before we throw any error in the user journey. How can we implement this as the user journey gets broken as soon as login-nonInteractive throws a password exception?

Answer (score 1):

1. On `login-noninteractive` technical profile called as Validation Technical profile from your Login Technical profile, set `"ContinueOnError"="true"`

   ```xml
       <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
         <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" "ContinueOnError"="true"/>
         </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
       </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
2. Inside `login-noninteractive` technical profile, set a `defaultValue` for `objectId`, eg `"DefaultValue"="badPassword"`

   ```xml
       <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
         <OutputClaims>
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" "DefaultValue"="badPassword"/>
       </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
3. In your Login Technical profile apply a precondition to the next validation technical profile, such that it only executes if `objectId!=badPassword`. Here call a technical profile to perform the workload for the bad password scenario.

   ```xml
     <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
         <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" "ContinueOnError"="true"/>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Run-Custom-BadPwd-Logic">
           <Preconditions>
             <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
               <Value>objectId</Value>
               <Value>badPassword</Value>
               <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
             </Precondition>
           </Preconditions>
         </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
       </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
     </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
4. Now we need to stop the flow for bad password. Call another validation technical profile with a precondition `skip if objectId!=badPassword`.

   ```xml
     <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
         <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" "ContinueOnError"="true"/>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Run-Custom-BadPwd-Logic">
           <Preconditions>
             <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
               <Value>objectId</Value>
               <Value>badPassword</Value>
               <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
             </Precondition>
           </Preconditions>
         </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Block-BadPwd-User">
           <Preconditions>
             <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
               <Value>objectId</Value>
               <Value>badPassword</Value>
               <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
             </Precondition>
           </Preconditions>
         </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
       </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
     </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
5. This (Block-BadPwd-User) should call a [claims transform technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile), which performs a boolean assertion. First call a claim transform to compare `objectId` with `"badPassword"`, output a boolean claim (booleanBadPassword=true/false). The a second claim transform to [compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#compareclaims) `booleanBadPassword` with a boolean (false). Use an [AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue) transform here, which will throw an error if the `booleanBadPassword` is not equal to `false`.

   ```xml
   <TechnicalProfile Id="Block-BadPwd-User">
     <DisplayName>Block-BadPwd-User</DisplayName>
       <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
       <OutputClaims>
         <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="booleanBadPassword" />
       </OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaimsTransformations>
           <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="compareObjectIdValue" />
           <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertValueIsFalse" />
       </OutputClaimsTransformations>
   </TechnicalProfile>
   ```

   ```xml
   <ClaimsTransformation Id="compareObjectIdValue" TransformationMethod="CompareClaimToValue">
     <InputClaims>
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
     </InputClaims>
     <InputParameters>
       <InputParameter Id="compareTo" DataType="string" Value="badPassword" />
       <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="equal" />
       <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
     </InputParameters>
     <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="booleanBadPassword" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
     </OutputClaims>
   </ClaimsTransformation>

   <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertValueIsFalse" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
     <InputClaims>
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="booleanBadPassword" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
     </InputClaims>
     <InputParameters>
       <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
     </InputParameters>
   </ClaimsTransformation>
   ```

Comment: <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" "DefaultValue"="badPassword"/> I am not able to get the deault Value of objectID here. May be because loginNonInteractive tech profile tend to fail due to wrong password scenario... how do I make this work.

Comment: AssertValueIsFalse-- will raise an exception on the wrong password and it stops the exception by showing the error message. we have a counter which increments based on the number of password attempts
and on the 4th attempt, we need to integrate a captcha and on the 5th attempt, we need to lock the account and show an error paragraph message.

But this AssertValueISfalse will stop the execution..

Comment: Remove the assert and call your API that returns a HTTP409  once count is reached.

Comment: <ClaimsTransformation Id="thirdattempt" TransformationMethod="AssertNumber">            <InputClaims>            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_passwordretryattempts" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>            </InputClaims>            <InputParameters>            <InputParameter Id="Operator" DataType="string" Value="EQUAL"/>            <InputParameter Id="CompareToValue" DataType="int" Value="3"/>            <InputParameter Id="throwError" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />            </InputParameters>                       </ClaimsTransformation>

Comment: We have the assert Number function to check the no of password incorrect attempts.. on each attempt we need to throw a different kinds of errors.. Since the TransformationMethod="AssertNumber"
The error message AssertNumbererror message will be displayed for the 4 attempts... We need to display different errors.

Could you please let us know if there any ways we can achieve this

Comment: And also can we add any expression to the User Error message ...something line $(variable) for example $(CounterVariable) like how we do it in Java code /any other languages... so that it can display the number in the error message instead of adding the static value to the error message

Comment: Have the API deliver the message based on the count it is holding.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-validation-error-message

Comment: We have the Rest API which is delivering the error message based on the counter Value... Could you please help us how to show these error messages on the same login screen now ? On every attempt it should display the different error messages.



for example : {UsermessaageifBooleanClaimsareNotequal} we harcoded the error message here, so that it can show it on the same login page. Now The rest API retruning it as Usermessage Output claim, we are getting the error messages as string but unable to display it on the same screen